# Error generating Swagger server (Python Flask) from Swagger editor

Tags: python, flask, swagger, connexion

I've used the Swagger Editor to manually generate my Swagger spec file and generated the files for a Python Flask server. Following the README I installed connexion, but when I run `python app.py` I get the error: 
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack. Any ideas?

Full stack trace below:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "connexion.api"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.add_api('swagger.yaml')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/connexion/app.py", line 144, in add_api
    debug=self.debug)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/connexion/api.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.add_paths()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/connexion/api.py", line 198, in add_paths
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/connexion/api.py", line 187, in add_paths
    self.add_operation(method, path, endpoint, path_parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/connexion/api.py", line 160, in add_operation
    resolver=self.resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/connexion/operation.py", line 168, in __init__
    resolution = resolver.resolve(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 50, in resolve
    return Resolution(self.resolve_function_from_operation_id(operation_id), operation_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 71, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
    return self.function_resolver(operation_id)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/connexion/utils.py", line 106, in get_function_from_name
    module_name, attr_path1 = module_name.rsplit('.', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: Please open a ticket via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues for tracking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this as well. From what I see, the generated code from Swagger seems to assume you're using Python 3. While connexion supports both Python 2.7 & 3.4+, it does need a `__init__.py` file in the generated `python-flask-server/` base directory as well as inside the `controllers/` subdirectory to work for Python 2.7 (Implicit Namespace Packages were introduced in Python 3.3). If you create those 2 empty files after generating the code, things should work. If the Swagger generator wants to support Python 2.7 (since connexion allows for it), it would just need to provide those files as well.

Comment: That solved this problem, but ran into other issues: 
def some_function(p1, p2) -> str: invalid syntax in default_controller.py. @letsgoblue Did you get this working with Python 2.7?

Comment: @tw1742: Ah yes, changed that as well - type hints are new in Python 3.5+, so to get that Python 2.7 compatible, just remove the ` -> str` & similar portions in that file and you'll be all set.

Comment: Ok, the app is running now but no content is displayed and it's returning a 404.

Comment: Sounds like a different issue altogether at that point then. You might consider what your endpoints are doing, what port the server is running on, the type of http request (get, post, et al), and the url you're trying to access, for starters.